# Enabling Tenant-Specific OAuth Endpoints (TSE) in SFMC Connector breaks the integration and email spams sysads

Tags: marketing-cloud

Our SFDC/SFMC connector frequently informed via Email to the sysad that read:

```
A Marketing Cloud Connect authentication token expired for this Marketing Cloud business unit and Salesforce org.

Org Name: Myorg
Org ID: 00D...
Business Unit Name: Foo Industries
Business Unit MID: 7xxxxx

To avoid interruption of service with Marketing Cloud Connect, reconnect your Marketing Cloud Connect API User immediately. Follow these steps to refresh your API user token.

Log in to your Sales or Service Cloud org as the Marketing Cloud Connect admin.
Navigate to the Marketing Cloud tab.
To navigate to Marketing Cloud Connect settings, click Configure Marketing Cloud Connector.
Click Change API User.
Re-enter your Marketing Cloud API user credentials for the affected business unit.
```

These emails occurred daily and then would suddenly stop, then recur. As admin, I finally got tired of this and per [SFMC Help doc on Tenant Specific Endpoints (TSE)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?type=5&id=mc_rn_october_2019_mcc_jwt_compatibility.htm) decided to enable TSE to stamp out once and for all the expired authentication token emails.

### I enabled TSE and then everything broke

```
Developer script exception from Helix : 'et4ae5.phoenixSendControl' for job id '7071Q0000BAoqY2' :
  Attempt to de-reference a null object  // generated every 15 mins

Developer script exception from Helix : et4ae5.updateBURecord : et4ae5.updateBURecord:
execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.QueryException: 
  List has no rows for assignment to SObject Trigger.et4ae5.updateBURecord: line 15, column 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hat tip to SFMC Support which doggedly and intelligently helped me work through this*

- Per SFMC Support, the `A Marketing Cloud Connect authentication token expired for ..` email is caused by a race condition which affected some orgs; hence the recommendation to go to TSE to resolve.
- Our SFDC Marketing Cloud Integration User had a custom profile with a lot of permissions, but apparently the TSE feature requires permissions available to `System Administrator` profile that were not present in our custom profile.  SFMC Support states that `System Administrator` is all that is officially supported.  *Of course, as we know, each SFDC Release adds new permissions to OOTB Profiles so even custom profiles cloned from `System Administrator` may stop working in some future SFDC/SFMC integration.*

So, the fix was:

- Make the SFMC Integration User in SFDC use `System Administrator` profile
- Rebuild / configure the `Marketing Cloud Connector Settings`. (use the Marketing Cloud tab in SFDC to do this)
- Rebuild / configure the Business Units within the Marketing Cloud Connector Settings